# How to validate JWS using square/go-jose package

Tags: node.js, security, go, jose, json-web-signature

I am generating a JSON web signature in JavaScript using node-jws package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jws). In Headers, I am giving crit: ["exp"] and exp: someTimeStamp. The snippet given below is used in generating the JWS:

```js
let token = jws.sign({
  header: { alg: 'HS256', crit: ["exp"], exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60) },
  payload: "somestring" ,
  privateKey: 'supersecret',
});
```

I am verifying this token in Golang using the snippet given below:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/square/go-jose"
)

func main() {
    jsonWebSig, err := jose.ParseSigned(token)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    payload, err := jsonWebSig.Verify([]byte("supersecret"))

    fmt.Println(string(payload))
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

The above code in GO works if I don't give the crit: ["exp"] in header while generating the token in JS. Otherwise, it gives me the error saying `square/go-jose: error in cryptographic primitive`.

I have to use crit: ["exp"] in headers at any cost. Is there any way to verify this?

Comment: If you can, try to avoid JOSE/JWT as the standard has some flaws that only an aware library would handle. (source : https://twitter.com/FiloSottile/status/1229805464810074114)